# Rails and SQL Injection: Is this safe?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, code-injection

```
@usersfound = User.find_by_sql(["

SELECT * from users where name @@ plainto_tsquery('english', ?) LIMIT 20 offset ?

  ",@query,@offset])
```

See above, is this safe from sql injection? I am very new to doing direct sql commands on a database in rails. (I am aware there may be other ways of doing this SPECIFIC query, but I am wondering if in general, using find_by_sql and that kind of insertion of vars is safe - I have some difficult queries with subselects and joins that are really possible to do with ActiveRecord.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that should be safe. If you trace through the code you'll find that your `find_by_sql` call ends up calling [`PGconn#send_query_prepared`](http://rubydoc.info/gems/pg/0.11.0/PGconn#send_query_prepared-instance_method) with the bind parameters being carried along as little more than baggage; the `send_query_prepared` method is just a wrapper for the [`PQsendQueryPrepared` API call in `libpq`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-async.html):

```
static VALUE
pgconn_send_query_prepared(int argc, VALUE *argv, VALUE self)
{
    /* ... bunch of boiler plate marshalling stuff ... */
    result = PQsendQueryPrepared(conn, StringValuePtr(name), nParams, 
        (const char * const *)paramValues, paramLengths, paramFormats, 
        resultFormat);
    /* ... */
}
```

The bind parameters end up in `paramValues`. So you should be fine unless there are bugs in PostgreSQL's C library prepared statement handling.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting dynamic values into a query using query parameters is safe.

But it depends on whether Rails is "faking" query parameters, and is actually combining @query and @offset into the SQL string before preparing the statement.  Then it's only as safe as the implementation of escaping in Rails.